# Как запустить Tomcat из класса, который не является сервлетом?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tomcat, servlet

С сервлетами всё понятно. Но как запустить Tomcat из класса, отвечающего за создание фрейма JavaFX (экстендит Application)? Суть в том, что должен производиться логин как с веб-страницы, так и с лаунчера. Чтобы организовать сверку с уже зарегистрированными пользователями из БД (подключенный к Tomcat MySQL), нужно к этой самой БД получить доступ (запущенный Tomcat). Если неправильный логин - отправляет на страницу регистрации (соответствующий сервлет), если правильный - все равно открывается webpage, но уже с игрой. С сервлетами main не юзается, так как запускать Tomcat из класса JavaFX?

Посматриваю на ServletContextEvent, но пока не понимаю, как его применить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете многопользовательскую сетевую игру, которая должна быть доступна как в браузере, так и с отдельного клиента?

Comment: Да. Но с клиента выполняется строго вход. Сама игра в браузере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У томката есть свой файл `bat`, через который он запускается.

с класса его запустить через Командную строку:

```
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c startup.bat", null, new File("E:\\Programs\\Tomcat 8.5.20\\bin"));
```

Укажите путь к папке `bin` вашего `TomCat`.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.

Comment: @Николай поставь галочку, пожалуйста)